# Dynamic Blueprints in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 models, **Model** & **Characteristic**, where a characteristic belongs to a model and a model can have many characteristics.
Each characteristic can have more than one translation (I'm using Mobility for the translation, so that the same Characteristic can contain its own translations).

The problem is, which language in which the characteristics were translated, it's dynamic.

My blueprint now is like this

```
        field :characteristics do |model|
      model.characteristics.where(active: true).map do |characteristic|
        characteristic_assets = characteristic.characteristic_assets.map do |asset|
          {
            'url' => asset.file.url,
            'category' => asset.category
          }
        end
        model.languages.map do |language|
          {
            'title' => "characteristic.title_#{language}",
            'description' => characteristic.description,
            'assets' => characteristic_assets
          }
        end
      end
    end
```

But when I received the blueprint info on the front, I see it, for example, like **characteristic.title_fr** instead of the value.

How can I send the value correctly?? Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you set `I18n.locale` in your project?

Comment: Do you mean in the gemfile.lock?

Comment: No in your controller. Otherwise the controller wouldn’t know what language to use when to respond to the request. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: My objective would be to send the characeristics in all the available languages. Trying to loop through the languages in the model